# How to neatly resize a MudBlazor table with an extra field in the tool bar?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, mudblazor

I'm practicing Blazor with the MudBlazor plugin and I want to make my table function at different screen widths.

I added an additional field to the table's toolbar for filtering the data. The tools look good on larger devices:

[image]

But not on smaller devices the title of the table is not visible and the search bar is on top of the table headers:

[image]

Ideally, this is how I'd want the tools to stack in the toolbar on a smaller screen:

[image]

I tried styling it in many ways with no luck. I feel like the code I have makes sense, but for some reason it doesn't work. I couldn't find anything in [MudBlazor table docs](https://mudblazor.com/components/table) that would help.

[Reproducible example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wuwRaxuPzeUKSWzm)

_Main.razor:

```
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudTable Items="@Elements" Hover="@true" Striped="@true" Dense="@true" HorizontalScrollbar="true" RowsPerPage="15" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.None">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudGrid>
            <MudItem xs="12" sm="4">
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xs="12" sm="4">
                <MudSelect Dense="true" T="string" Label="Coffee" Variant="Variant.Text" Class="mt-0">
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Tyrannosaur")" />
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Triceratops")" />
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Mike Rex")" />
                </MudSelect>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xs="12" sm="4">
                <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString1" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

@code {
    private string searchString1 = "";

    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }
}
```

Element.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
{
    public class Element
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("small")]
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public double Molar { get; set; }
        public IList<int> Electrons { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the `MudGrid` outside the `MudTable`.  The `<ToolBarContent>` obviously doesn't have the right formatting to deal with the MudGrid.  I've added a bit of margin to create some separation with the table.

```
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="4" Class="mb-2">
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="4">
        <MudSelect Dense="true" T="string" Label="Coffee" Variant="Variant.Text" Class="mt-0">
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Tyrannosaur")" />
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Triceratops")" />
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Mike Rex")" />
        </MudSelect>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="4" Class="mb-2">
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString1" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Hover="@true" Striped="@true" Dense="@true" HorizontalScrollbar="true" RowsPerPage="15" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.None">
//....
```

See how it looks [here](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cacxEHYFLcwEFbAM).

Comment: After some minor styling of the MudItem and MudGrid elements, your solution works and looks perfect. Thank you!